# Meaning of 課せられた

Tags: conjugations

Reading the definition of 任務 from 明鏡国語辞典, I found:

> その人に**課せられた**、果たさなくてはならないつとめ。

This seems like 課す (which means to impose a task or tax) in potential and passive form, but I dont understand who it is that is supposed to "be able to 課す". Could someone explain?

---

I found a definition for 課せられる in [weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%AA%B2%E3%81%9B%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B#:%7E:text=%E4%B8%BB%E3%81%AB%E3%80%81%E6%9E%9C%E3%81%9F%E3%81%99%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE,%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A9%E3%82%92%E6%84%8F%E5%91%B3%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E8%A1%A8%E7%8F%BE%E3%80%82) which I understand.

> 主に、果たすべきものとして引き受けさせられること、(責任・責務を負わせられること、などを意味する表現。)

Does this have any relationship with 課す, or should I just learn 課せられる as it's own thing?

Comment: FYI: https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1411534249, https://zonia.hatenadiary.org/entry/20070213/1171375246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

課せられた here is the passive form of 課す. There's no actor who performs it and we are not even conscious of him when we only hear that sentense.

You can just think of it that "The person has a duty" or something like that.

Comment: Could it also mean "The duty assigned **by** that person"?

Comment: No, it couldn't if "that person" you meant was その人 in the sentence. その人 can only be the passive recipient of the action.

Comment: @Marronnier Is the その人 marked with に because its the indirect object, not the agent?

Comment: @Marronnier how should I say "The duty assigned by that person", then?

Comment: @Mauro I went to bed and thought about it this morning. Yeah, you're right. it could bean that way. However, I personally say "その人によって課せられた" in that case. Anyway, I can almost assure you that その人 here is used as an object.

Comment: @firuvi Yes, it is. に is the indirect object. It can be used as a passive agent, though https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%AB. As Mauro said, it could mean that way, but when I ask myself and my friends about it, we seem to think of the indirect object usage first.